# How to pass DropZone JSON object to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, dropzone.js

In my Angular app, I'm using Dropzone with JQuery to upload files. I'm successfully able to upload file to my server and receive the response data. Now I need to pass that response data from JQuery to my AngularJS controller.

This is my dropzone code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Smart Wizard
  $('#wizard').smartWizard({labelFinish:'Upload'});

      $('#file-dropzone').dropzone({ 
        url: "UploadData/",
        maxFilesize: 1024000,
        paramName: "uploadfile",
        acceptedFiles: ".csv",
        maxFiles: 1,
        dictDefaultMessage: "Drop CSV file here",
        maxThumbnailFilesize: 5,
        dictMaxFilesExceeded: "You can only uplaod one file",
        init: function() {

            this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
                $(".busy-modal").show();

                formData.append("format", $("#format").val());

            });

            this.on('success', function(file, json) {
                $(".busy-modal").hide();
                alert(JSON.stringify(json));
            });

            this.on('addedfile', function(file) {

            });

        }
    });
});

function ResetDropZone()
{
    Dropzone.forElement("#file-dropzone").removeAllFiles(true);
}

</script>
```

This is where I receive response data in JSON.

```
this.on('success', function(file, json) {
            $(".busy-modal").hide();
            alert(JSON.stringify(json));
        });
```

I need to pass this json object to AngularJS controller. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got to do it by myself. Here's how:

I added a hidden text input with `ng-model` and `ng-change` attributes.

```
<input type="text" hidden id="fileResult" ng-model="fileResult" ng-change="fileResult_Changed()"/>
```

In my dropzone success function I changed value of that field and ***triggered input*** so that my `ng-change` event would fire.

```
this.on('success', function(file, json) {
                $(".busy-modal").hide();
                //alert(JSON.stringify(json));

                $("#fileResult").val(JSON.stringify(json));
                $("#fileResult").trigger('input');
            });
```

And this is my `ng-change` event in my controller where I received data successfully

```
$scope.fileResult_Changed = function()
{
    alert($scope.fileResult);
}
```

Ta-da!

Answer (score 0):

Create `dropzone` directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('dropzone', ['$cookie', function ($cookie) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {
          fileList: '=?'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var config = {
                url: '/upload',
                maxFilesize: 16,
                paramName: "file_content",
                maxThumbnailFilesize: 10,
                parallelUploads: 1,
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                headers: {
                  'X-CSRFToken': $cookies.get('csrftoken')
                }
            };
            var eventHandlers = {
                'addedfile': function(file) {
                  var dz = this;
                  scope.$apply(function () {
                      scope.file = file;
                      if (dz.files[1]!=null) {
                          dz.removeFile(dz.files[0]);
                      }
                      scope.fileAdded = true;
                      scope.processDropzone();
                  });
                },
                'success': function (file, response) {
                  // Do some thing on success
                  scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.resetFile(file);
                  };
                },
                'error': function (file, reason) {
                  // Do something on error
                }
            };

            scope.dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config);

            angular.forEach(eventHandlers, function(handler, event) {
                scope.dropzone.on(event, handler);
            });
            scope.processDropzone = function() {
                scope.dropzone.processQueue();
            };
            scope.resetDropzone = function() {
                scope.dropzone.removeAllFiles();
            };
            scope.resetFile = function(file) {
                scope.dropzone.removeFile(file);
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I'm avoiding using custom directive until an official one is provided from dropzone.

Comment: Dropzone's site for angularjs integration provides link to http://www.cantangosolutions.com/blog/Easy-File-Upload-Using-DropzoneJS-AngularJs-And-Spring where they are creating custom directive. I think they'll never provide `official` (i.e. common, sufficient for all user cases) directive. Directive is your life simplifier, so just write it on your own.